# YII: how to display related table field on attributes?

Tags: php, yii

I am new with YII and I have a question ... 
I have a model like

```
Person {
   $id ; 
   $name ; 
   $address ; 
}


Car{
   $id ;
   $carLicenseNumber ; 
   $person_id ; // BELONGS TO PERSON 
}
```

I have a CJuiAutoComplete but I have no idea how to display person name on the field when it want to update

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'id'=>'person',
    'name'=>'person',

    'attribute'=> 'person->name', // I WANT THIS but no idea how to do this ... 

    'source'=>$this->createUrl('person/suggestPerson'),
    'options'=>array(
        'delay'=>150,
        'minLength'=>2,
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
        'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
            $('#label').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#temp_person_id').val(ui.item.id);
        }"
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'size'=>'40'
    ),
));
```

How to display person->name  on the attribute ?

note: $model is Car instance

I tried to use temporary variable like

$temp = $model->person->name ; 
then assign $temp to 'attribute'=>$temp 
it work well ...

I just want to know how the proper way to assign related field on the textfield or autocomplete field.

Comment: ok, in this form of yours do you plan to take new values for `person` (person details like name, id, address) also?, in addition to `car` details that is.

Comment: hmm it seems like you have found a solution already, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I did chat with some YII developers on Live Chat  I found the solution for this

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'model'=>$model->person, // change this to model->person instead of model
    'id'=>'person_name',
    'name'=>'person_name',

    'attribute'=> 'name', // just name

    'source'=>$this->createUrl('person/suggestPerson'),
    'options'=>array(
        'delay'=>150,
        'minLength'=>2,
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
        'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
            $('#label').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#temp_person_id').val(ui.item.id);
        }"
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'size'=>'40'
    ),
));
```